# Why is my server response so high (First Byte Time)?

Tags: server, webserver, hosting, server-response

One of my websites has suddenly become extremely slow in server response - currently 41859 ms First Byte Time.

Already talked to hosting provider, but they did not notice any changes or problems with the server. So I am lost on what is the problem. Already tried plugins for caching and image optimization but I know that won't help.

Does anyone know what might be the problem? I've also run a security check but nothing was found, in case it's a virus.

Any ideas?

Comment: the question is too vague and I think there must be hundreds of blog posts that will talk about how to go about troubleshooting a slow web response. If you have tried something specific, with a specific tool and have collected some data and then post a question that is more narrowed down, perhaps we can help here.

Comment: Found out from client that there was an malware he noticed about half a year ago. It was left there. I just got there and the site was in a terrible state in response to malware attack. It also had backdoors installed.

I found out a theme was attacked and there was also separate issues all over the web. The issue is solved. 

How do you flag the issue as solved?

Comment: the best way would be post what you just posted as comment, as an answer. You an answer your own questions, and there is nothing wrong with it.